# Fatorial duplo no r com letras para diferenciação

Tags: r, comparação, anova

Prezados estou tentando realizar uma analise fatorial dupla ou two-away anova.
 Gostaria de saber como faço para gerar as letras de diferenciação entre tratamentos para os dois fatores.
 Essa diferenciação é comum em artigos científicos no qual geralmente é apresentado em tabelas, com as letras minusculas diferenciando as médias na coluna e as maiúsculas na linha.

Para tal segue os dados que utilizei:

```
    data <- structure(list(Parcela = c(1, 8, 14, 19, 2, 9, 15, 17, 3, 10, 
13, 18, 4, 6, 12, 20, 5, 7, 11, 16, 40, 35, 29, 23, 39, 34, 30, 
25, 38, 32, 26, 21, 37, 33, 28, 22, 36, 31, 27, 24, 41, 47, 51, 
59, 42, 55, NA, 60, 43, 48, 52, 57, 44, 46, 54, 58, 45, 50, 53, 
56, 80, 71, 67, 62, 79, 73, 68, 64, 78, 72, 69, 61, 77, 74, 70, 
63, 76, 75, 66, 65, 81, 90, 93, 99, 82, 86, 91, 96, 83, 89, 92, 
97, 84, 88, 95, 100, 85, 87, 94, 98, 120, 114, 106, 102, 119, 
111, 110, 101, 118, 115, 109, 103, 117, 113, 108, 105, 116, 112, 
107, 104, 121, 128, 134, 136, 122, 129, 131, 137, 123, 127, 132, 
140, 124, 126, 135, 139, 125, 130, 133, 138, 160, 155, 146, 143, 
159, 154, 148, 142, 158, 152, 150, 145, 157, 153, 147, 141, 156, 
151, 149, 144, 161, 170, 174, 176, 162, 168, 172, 180, 163, 167, 
171, 178, 164, 169, 175, 179, 165, 166, 173, 177, 201, 206, 212, 
219, 202, 207, 215, 217, 203, 209, 211, 218, 204, 210, 213, 216, 
205, 208, 214, 220, 240, 234, 227, 222, 239, 235, 228, 224, 238, 
232, 230, 225, 237, 233, 229, 223, 236, 231, 226, 221, 241, 246, 
254, 260, 242, 247, 251, 256, 243, 250, 255, 257, 244, 248, 253, 
259, 245, 249, 252, 258, 280, 275, 267, 263, 279, 274, 269, 265, 
278, 273, 270, 264, 277, 272, 268, 262, 276, 271, 266, 261, 281, 
286, 294, 299, 282, 289, 295, 297, 283, 287, 292, 300, 284, 288, 
291, 298, 285, 290, 293, 296, 320, 314, 307, 301, 319, 313, 308, 
305, 318, 311, 309, 302, 317, 315, 306, 304, 316, 312, 310, 303, 
321, 327, 335, 337, 322, 326, 332, 340, 323, 328, 333, 336, 324, 
330, 334, 338, 325, 329, 331, 339, 360, 355, 346, 341, 359, 354, 
349, 345, 358, 351, 348, 344, 357, 353, 350, 342, 356, 352, 347, 
343), cul = c("BRS 1001IPRO", "BRS 1001IPRO", "BRS 1001IPRO", 
"BRS 1001IPRO", "BRS 1001IPRO", "BRS 1001IPRO", "BRS 1001IPRO", 
"BRS 1001IPRO", "BRS 1001IPRO", "BRS 1001IPRO", "BRS 1001IPRO", 
"BRS 1001IPRO", "BRS 1001IPRO", "BRS 1001IPRO", "BRS 1001IPRO", 
"BRS 1001IPRO", "BRS 1001IPRO", "BRS 1001IPRO", "BRS 1001IPRO", 
"BRS 1001IPRO", "BRS 1003IPRO", "BRS 1003IPRO", "BRS 1003IPRO", 
"BRS 1003IPRO", "BRS 1003IPRO", "BRS 1003IPRO", "BRS 1003IPRO", 
"BRS 1003IPRO", "BRS 1003IPRO", "BRS 1003IPRO", "BRS 1003IPRO", 
"BRS 1003IPRO", "BRS 1003IPRO", "BRS 1003IPRO", "BRS 1003IPRO", 
"BRS 1003IPRO", "BRS 1003IPRO", "BRS 1003IPRO", "BRS 1003IPRO", 
"BRS 1003IPRO", "BRS 1007IPRO", "BRS 1007IPRO", "BRS 1007IPRO", 
"BRS 1007IPRO", "BRS 1007IPRO", "BRS 1007IPRO", "BRS 1007IPRO", 
"BRS 1007IPRO", "BRS 1007IPRO", "BRS 1007IPRO", "BRS 1007IPRO", 
"BRS 1007IPRO", "BRS 1007IPRO", "BRS 1007IPRO", "BRS 1007IPRO", 
"BRS 1007IPRO", "BRS 1007IPRO", "BRS 1007IPRO", "BRS 1007IPRO", 
"BRS 1007IPRO", "BRS 1010IPRO", "BRS 1010IPRO", "BRS 1010IPRO", 
"BRS 1010IPRO", "BRS 1010IPRO", "BRS 1010IPRO", "BRS 1010IPRO", 
"BRS 1010IPRO", "BRS 1010IPRO", "BRS 1010IPRO", "BRS 1010IPRO", 
"BRS 1010IPRO", "BRS 1010IPRO", "BRS 1010IPRO", "BRS 1010IPRO", 
"BRS 1010IPRO", "BRS 1010IPRO", "BRS 1010IPRO", "BRS 1010IPRO", 
"BRS 1010IPRO", "BRS 1074IPRO", "BRS 1074IPRO", "BRS 1074IPRO", 
"BRS 1074IPRO", "BRS 1074IPRO", "BRS 1074IPRO", "BRS 1074IPRO", 
"BRS 1074IPRO", "BRS 1074IPRO", "BRS 1074IPRO", "BRS 1074IPRO", 
"BRS 1074IPRO", "BRS 1074IPRO", "BRS 1074IPRO", "BRS 1074IPRO", 
"BRS 1074IPRO", "BRS 1074IPRO", "BRS 1074IPRO", "BRS 1074IPRO", 
"BRS 1074IPRO", "BRS 413RR", "BRS 413RR", "BRS 413RR", "BRS 413RR", 
"BRS 413RR", "BRS 413RR", "BRS 413RR", "BRS 413RR", "BRS 413RR", 
"BRS 413RR", "BRS 413RR", "BRS 413RR", "BRS 413RR", "BRS 413RR", 
"BRS 413RR", "BRS 413RR", "BRS 413RR", "BRS 413RR", "BRS 413RR", 
"BRS 413RR", "BRS 388RR", "BRS 388RR", "BRS 388RR", "BRS 388RR", 
"BRS 388RR", "BRS 388RR", "BRS 388RR", "BRS 388RR", "BRS 388RR", 
"BRS 388RR", "BRS 388RR", "BRS 388RR", "BRS 388RR", "BRS 388RR", 
"BRS 388RR", "BRS 388RR", "BRS 388RR", "BRS 388RR", "BRS 388RR", 
"BRS 388RR", "BRS 399RR", "BRS 399RR", "BRS 399RR", "BRS 399RR", 
"BRS 399RR", "BRS 399RR", "BRS 399RR", "BRS 399RR", "BRS 399RR", 
"BRS 399RR", "BRS 399RR", "BRS 399RR", "BRS 399RR", "BRS 399RR", 
"BRS 399RR", "BRS 399RR", "BRS 399RR", "BRS 399RR", "BRS 399RR", 
"BRS 399RR", "BRB14-211566", "BRB14-211566", "BRB14-211566", 
"BRB14-211566", "BRB14-211566", "BRB14-211566", "BRB14-211566", 
"BRB14-211566", "BRB14-211566", "BRB14-211566", "BRB14-211566", 
"BRB14-211566", "BRB14-211566", "BRB14-211566", "BRB14-211566", 
"BRB14-211566", "BRB14-211566", "BRB14-211566", "BRB14-211566", 
"BRB14-211566", "BR11-3381", "BR11-3381", "BR11-3381", "BR11-3381", 
"BR11-3381", "BR11-3381", "BR11-3381", "BR11-3381", "BR11-3381", 
"BR11-3381", "BR11-3381", "BR11-3381", "BR11-3381", "BR11-3381", 
"BR11-3381", "BR11-3381", "BR11-3381", "BR11-3381", "BR11-3381", 
"BR11-3381", "BR12-511", "BR12-511", "BR12-511", "BR12-511", 
"BR12-511", "BR12-511", "BR12-511", "BR12-511", "BR12-511", "BR12-511", 
"BR12-511", "BR12-511", "BR12-511", "BR12-511", "BR12-511", "BR12-511", 
"BR12-511", "BR12-511", "BR12-511", "BR12-511", "BR10-87465", 
"BR10-87465", "BR10-87465", "BR10-87465", "BR10-87465", "BR10-87465", 
"BR10-87465", "BR10-87465", "BR10-87465", "BR10-87465", "BR10-87465", 
"BR10-87465", "BR10-87465", "BR10-87465", "BR10-87465", "BR10-87465", 
"BR10-87465", "BR10-87465", "BR10-87465", "BR10-87465", "BRR12-83021", 
"BRR12-83021", "BRR12-83021", "BRR12-83021", "BRR12-83021", "BRR12-83021", 
"BRR12-83021", "BRR12-83021", "BRR12-83021", "BRR12-83021", "BRR12-83021", 
"BRR12-83021", "BRR12-83021", "BRR12-83021", "BRR12-83021", "BRR12-83021", 
"BRR12-83021", "BRR12-83021", "BRR12-83021", "BRR12-83021", "BRR12-53050", 
"BRR12-53050", "BRR12-53050", "BRR12-53050", "BRR12-53050", "BRR12-53050", 
"BRR12-53050", "BRR12-53050", "BRR12-53050", "BRR12-53050", "BRR12-53050", 
"BRR12-53050", "BRR12-53050", "BRR12-53050", "BRR12-53050", "BRR12-53050", 
"BRR12-53050", "BRR12-53050", "BRR12-53050", "BRR12-53050", "BRR12-2497", 
"BRR12-2497", "BRR12-2497", "BRR12-2497", "BRR12-2497", "BRR12-2497", 
"BRR12-2497", "BRR12-2497", "BRR12-2497", "BRR12-2497", "BRR12-2497", 
"BRR12-2497", "BRR12-2497", "BRR12-2497", "BRR12-2497", "BRR12-2497", 
"BRR12-2497", "BRR12-2497", "BRR12-2497", "BRR12-2497", "BR12-4929", 
"BR12-4929", "BR12-4929", "BR12-4929", "BR12-4929", "BR12-4929", 
"BR12-4929", "BR12-4929", "BR12-4929", "BR12-4929", "BR12-4929", 
"BR12-4929", "BR12-4929", "BR12-4929", "BR12-4929", "BR12-4929", 
"BR12-4929", "BR12-4929", "BR12-4929", "BR12-4929", "BR12-10309", 
"BR12-10309", "BR12-10309", "BR12-10309", "BR12-10309", "BR12-10309", 
"BR12-10309", "BR12-10309", "BR12-10309", "BR12-10309", "BR12-10309", 
"BR12-10309", "BR12-10309", "BR12-10309", "BR12-10309", "BR12-10309", 
"BR12-10309", "BR12-10309", "BR12-10309", "BR12-10309"), trat = c("Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", 
"Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Test.", 
"Test.", "Test.", "Test.", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", 
"Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Test.", "Test.", "Test.", 
"Test.", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", 
"Test.", "Test.", "Test.", "Test.", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", 
"Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Test.", "Test.", "Test.", 
"Test.", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", 
"Test.", "Test.", "Test.", "Test.", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", 
"Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Test.", "Test.", "Test.", 
"Test.", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", 
"Test.", "Test.", "Test.", "Test.", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", 
"Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Test.", "Test.", "Test.", 
"Test.", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", 
"Test.", "Test.", "Test.", "Test.", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", 
"Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Test.", "Test.", "Test.", 
"Test.", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", 
"Test.", "Test.", "Test.", "Test.", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", 
"Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Test.", "Test.", "Test.", 
"Test.", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", 
"Test.", "Test.", "Test.", "Test.", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", 
"Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Test.", "Test.", "Test.", 
"Test.", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", 
"Test.", "Test.", "Test.", "Test.", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", 
"Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Test.", "Test.", "Test.", 
"Test.", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (1,2)", 
"Boral 500 SC (1,2)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", 
"Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Boral 500 SC (2,4)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", "Sencor 480 (0,75)", 
"Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", "Sencor 480 (1,5)", 
"Test.", "Test.", "Test.", "Test."), rep = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), alt = c(87.4, 
95.9, 103.3, 94.2, 94.65, 93.2, 98.95, 87.45, 104.4, 103.4, 102.35, 
97.9, 96.7, 101.3, 97.95, 96.3, 102, 98.35, 98.8, 97.4, 64.05, 
71.8, 69.7, 65.4, 46.5, 37.15, 40.05, 44.2, 95.6, 92.35, 87.8, 
87.3, 93.25, 86.4, 93.4, 79.6, 91.3, 92.35, 90.15, 87.3, 82, 
81.15, 75.65, 85.35, 80.35, 75.45, 73.6, 72.9, 95.1, 84.75, 80.6, 
86.45, 89.8, 81.7, 81.7, 84.55, 92.65, 88.9, 89.7, 82.35, 81.3, 
76.55, 92.7, 79.45, 73.25, 42.6, 72.3, 65.6, 102.15, 97, 102.3, 
94.65, 103.4, 94.1, 98.2, 91.65, 104.25, 98.25, 104.05, 100.45, 
98.35, 106.4, 101.55, 94.9, 98.2, 103.35, 98.3, 101.8, 107.2, 
106.85, 104.45, 97.25, 106.2, 100.3, 99.9, 93, 111.15, 102.2, 
107.85, 98.65, 80.15, 75.35, 80.3, 72.5, 73.65, 78.5, 70.7, 76.95, 
77.55, 81.45, 80.95, 76.5, 78.25, 77.2, 81.5, 79.35, 82.55, 77.75, 
83.05, 79.6, 78.1, 78.8, 85.25, 82.25, 79.05, 76.55, 79, 78.85, 
86.6, 75.8, 86.1, 79.35, 77.6, 80.3, 80.4, 69.5, 81.95, 79.1, 
81.5, 80.6, 56.35, 71.85, 74.1, 63.2, 44.3, 37.1, 44.25, 37.25, 
82.65, 84.85, 78, 95.35, 89.15, 82.05, 90.15, 68.95, 89.85, 80.9, 
78.55, 85.7, 71.45, 65.4, 70.05, 71.45, 55.2, 44.7, 59.3, 45.2, 
80.75, 78.95, 75.25, 79.7, 81.2, 73.85, 84.15, 72.7, 81.2, 88, 
80.05, 71.8, 52.35, 69.5, 56.8, 53.2, 29.2, 41.85, 51.75, 37.35, 
65.45, 65.15, 66.5, 49.4, 75.5, 78.5, 67.9, 60.85, 69.15, 66.7, 
62.9, 63, 86.5, 106.75, 95.2, 99.75, 76.3, 89.35, 90.75, 87.45, 
99.8, 110.3, 98.3, 107.15, 99, 104.25, 95.75, 98.75, 102.15, 
106.9, 104.65, 97.5, 91.4, 86.3, 77.6, 87.4, 77.9, 79.5, 86.55, 
72.6, 89.25, 93.55, 86.15, 84.2, 81.1, 93.85, 77.4, 85.85, 87.15, 
96.45, 78.55, 80.4, 72.1, 70.15, 80.8, 77.15, 54.55, 67.7, 76.65, 
70.45, 76.5, 75.4, 80.65, 80.35, 74.3, 75.15, 79.75, 79.9, 76.25, 
82.45, 77.85, 85.5, 85.95, 90.4, 94.55, 98.3, 84.9, 84.35, 93.75, 
77.7, 92.55, 94.15, 100.05, 102.15, 82.55, 91.65, 96.1, 97.4, 
100.3, 97.85, 93.9, 97.3, 93.65, 112.15, 108.2, 111.4, 94.3, 
97.95, 107, 98.65, 110.9, 112.85, 111.65, 116.45, 100, 109.3, 
109.7, 107.4, 106.55, 113.5, 114, 117.8, 107.4, 114, 112.25, 
111, 105.7, 107, 114.9, 115.4, 112.8, 115.65, 113.35, 111.4, 
108.5, 112.1, 112.55, 113.5, 116.95, 116.65, 121.05, 119.6, 92.1, 
100.15, 100.15, 96.35, 91.2, 104.05, 95.7, 92.9, 104.7, 100.3, 
97.8, 99.1, 97.95, 103.85, 100.15, 101.55, 100.55, 100.3, 94.8, 
99.1)), .Names = c("Parcela", "cul", "trat", "rep", "alt"), row.names = c(NA, 
-340L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Com esses dados eu realizei as seguintes operações:

```
#setup das variaveis
cul <- as.factor(data$cul)
trat <- as.factor(data$trat)
rep <- as.factor(data$rep)
alt <- data$alt


aovalt <- aov(formula=alt ~ cul+trat+cul:trat, data=data)
model.tables(aovalt, "means")
```

Com o comando `model.tables` eu consigo praticamente a tabela que pretendo obter, porem me faltam as letras que demonstram as diferenças entre as cultivares e os tratamentos.

Para tal eu tentei:

```
tukey <- TukeyHSD(aovalt)
tukey$`cul:trat`[,4]
plot(tukey$`cul:trat`[,4])
HSD.test(cul, trt = alt)
```

Mas como é possível observar é gerado uma lista de comparação gigantesca, sendo essa abaixo apenas uma fração da lista.

> BR12-10309:Boral 500 SC (2,4)-BRR12-2497:Boral 500 SC (1,2)
>   9.580700e-01

Nessa amostra fica mais fácil observar o objetivo da minha pergunta: Na primeira linha está a comparação entre a cultivar "BR12-10309" tratada com "Boral 500 SC (2,4)" em comparação a média da cultivar "BRR12-2497" tratada com "Boral 500 SC (1,2)" e o valor de p "9.580700e-01" muito menor do que 0,05 ou seja significativo, portanto existe diferença entre essas médias, minha pergunta se dá como classificar essa diferença com letras, separando qual cultivar obteve a melhor média no tratamento x,y,z e etc... e dentro de cada cultivar qual o melhor tratamento a ser aplicados a ela.

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: O código não é reproduzível. O comando `data <- data.frame(var,trat,one,two,three)` exige os objetos `two` e `three` que não estão definidos. Para evitar confusão, sugiro editar a pergunta substituindo todo o primeiro bloco, de criação de dados, pelo resutado do comando `dput(data)`. E se for possível reescrever a pergunta, melhorando a redação com algumas vírgulas bem colocas e frases mais curtas (repare que não tem um único ponto final!), eu agradeço. Será mais fácil para entendermos qual é a dúvida de fato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu recomendo utilizar o pacote [emmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html) vinheta [Interaction analysis in emmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html#factors):

```
library(emmeans)
l1 <- emmeans(aovalt, "cul", "trat") # Cria o objeto emmeans no caso de interação
CLD(l1, Letter="abcdefghij") # Pede a exibição com as letras
trat = Boral 500 SC (1,2):
 cul            emmean       SE  df  lower.CL  upper.CL .group      
 BR11-3381     57.9625 2.671402 255  52.70168  63.22332  a          
 BRS 399RR     66.3750 2.671402 255  61.11418  71.63582  ab         
 BRS 1003IPRO  67.7375 2.671402 255  62.47668  72.99832  ab         
 BRB14-211566  69.5875 2.671402 255  64.32668  74.84832  abc        
 BRR12-83021   75.0500 2.671402 255  69.78918  80.31082   bcd       
 BRS 413RR     77.0750 2.671402 255  71.81418  82.33582   bcd       
 BRS 1007IPRO  81.0375 2.671402 255  75.77668  86.29832    cde      
 BRS 388RR     81.1000 2.671402 255  75.83918  86.36082    cde      
 BRS 1010IPRO  82.5000 2.671402 255  77.23918  87.76082    cdef     
 BR10-87465    85.6750 2.671402 255  80.41418  90.93582     defg    
 BRR12-53050   92.3000 2.671402 255  87.03918  97.56082      efgh   
 BRS 1001IPRO  95.2000 2.671402 255  89.93918 100.46082       fghi  
 BR12-511      97.0500 2.671402 255  91.78918 102.31082        ghi  
 BR12-10309    97.1875 2.671402 255  91.92668 102.44832        ghi  
 BRS 1074IPRO 100.3000 2.671402 255  95.03918 105.56082         hija
 BRR12-2497   106.3500 2.671402 255 101.08918 111.61082          ija
 BR12-4929    111.1625 2.671402 255 105.90168 116.42332           ja
```

Para cada tratamento, ele faz as comparações entre o "cul". Para exibir as comparações sem apresentar as letras, use:

```
summary(pairs(l1), infer = c(T,T))
trat = Boral 500 SC (1,2):
 contrast                    estimate       SE  df     lower.CL     upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 BR10-87465 - BR11-3381       27.7125 3.777933 255  14.51235057  40.91264943   7.335  <.0001
 BR10-87465 - BR12-10309     -11.5125 3.777933 255 -24.71264943   1.68764943  -3.047  0.1718
 BR10-87465 - BR12-4929      -25.4875 3.777933 255 -38.68764943 -12.28735057  -6.746  <.0001
 BR10-87465 - BR12-511       -11.3750 3.777933 255 -24.57514943   1.82514943  -3.011  0.1875
 BR10-87465 - BRB14-211566    16.0875 3.777933 255   2.88735057  29.28764943   4.258  0.0033
 BR10-87465 - BRR12-2497     -20.6750 3.777933 255 -33.87514943  -7.47485057  -5.473  <.0001
 BR10-87465 - BRR12-53050     -6.6250 3.777933 255 -19.82514943   6.57514943  -1.754  0.9430
```